# SSH apps for iPad that run 9.3.5 and earlier

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ios-appstore, ssh, downgrade

I own an iPad2 (I guess it's an iPad2, it's an old iPad, one of those that you can't update past 9.3.5). Not only that I can't update past iOS 9.3.5, most of the apps I was looking at require at least version 10.

I'm currently looking at some way of having SSH or Mosh available so I could do some programming work. Apps like Blink Shell or Termius require newer iOS versions so I'm stuck.

Is there any way of installing an older version of an app, or do you guys know of any app I can still use on my iPad that will provide me at least ability to SSH into other machines?